# How many different ways are there to deploy a website under azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud, serverless

Good day dear community,

i have a smaller project where i need to search for different possibilities to deploy a website under azure portal.

Personally i found 4 different ways how to do it.

1. App services
2. App functions Serverless **(which i dont understand how to deploy there a website)**
3. Install a VM and then deploy a website
4. Use docker to deploy your code

Question:
Are there any more ways to deploy a website under azure and can somebody explain the deployment of websites with serverless as i dont understand how to publish a website there. i just managed to get the httptriggers and i am confused with that.

Thanks in advance
sorry for any spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy to a website to a VM. But first you will have to setup the VM to be a web server. There are many different pre-configured images with either Linux or Windows OS. This will require you manage the OS of the VM.

An Azure App Service will abstract the OS and VM away from you. The OS will be managed for you and you can configure many settings through the Azure Portal. There are different plans that allow you to use more compute and/or memory. You can also setup Authentication through the portal. You can also elect to deploy you website inside a container to an App Service.

There are also Azure Function Apps which can be used. Azure Function Apps are not intended to serve as the backend to a website, but it can be. These are meant to serve only one purpose, not many like the backend of a whole website ( for example, you might use a different function app to serve content each page of a website instead of just one app service having multiple endpoints serving all pages of a website). With Azure function apps, you can deploy in a container or not in a container.

I am not sure what you mean by number 4, Container over docker. You can deploy a docker container an App Service or a Function App. You can deploy the container to docker hub or azure container registry (to name a couple), but that will not deploy your website so that it is accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so it is also possible then to play a bit around for example deploy a LAMP stack over docker in a created VM? The pricing will normally change to then?

Comment: You should be able to do that if you have Docker installed on the VM.